# I am getting flutter at the start in my response. Even when my response does not include flutter before the List of Objects

Tags: flutter, dio

Get request using dio package.

```
  void fetchData() async {
    try {
      var response = await dio.get(
        "http://localhost:8888/api/screen",
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
          lineData = response.data;
        });
      }
    } on DioError catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }
```

Getting response after printing lineData. This flutter keyword is added to my data.

```
    flutter: [{_id: id1, day: 1, data: 7.3, percent: 1.3}, {_id: id2, day: 2, data: 1.2, 
    percent: 0.5}]
```

Server response in post man. Without flutter at the start.

```
[
    {
    "_id": "<id1>",
    "day": 1,
    "data": 7.3,
    "percent": 1.3
    },
    {
    "_id": "<id2>",
    "day": 2,
    "data": 1.2,
    "percent": 0.5
    }
]
```

Comment: its not in your response. try using it in the application.

Comment: Using in the application @ManishDayma

Comment: anything you print in flutter will append "flutter:" to it. try printing the object in screen text.

Comment: @ManishDayma trying to print in text widget but it says "Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception."

Comment: show me code for the text widget

Comment: child: Text(lineData[0]["_id"].toString()), but its printing in print statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this code

```
  void fetchData() async {
    try {
      var response = await dio.get(
        "http://localhost:8888/api/screen",
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
          lineData = jsonDecode(response.data);
        });
      }
    } on DioError catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are printing your response on your **debug console**. If you are trying to print this response, **IDE** will always add a flutter append to your response.

You can try to show this response on your screen (for example, with `Text()`)